# RC transmitter and receiver for Raspberry Pi possible?

Tags: raspberry-pi, remote-control, frequency-modulation, amplitude-modulation

I've got a pet project in which I'm trying to write/build a self learning autopilot for my rc plane. I've got a Raspberry Pi with an IMU and a pitot tube in the plane and it can now control the servos of the plane. So far so good.

I'm now thinking about connectivity. I want to be able to send commands in json from my laptop to the Raspberry Pi in the plane. I got it working over wifi, but that means I need to take my router outside when I go flying. Plus the range of the wifi is not very good (I tested it outside and it comes to about 50 meters).

Conventional rc transmitters and receivers have way better ranges (up to 1000 meters) than my wifi from the router does, so I'm wondering how I can leverage that technology. I see plenty of rc receivers around to buy, but they all work with a number of channels, instead of a data link over which you can send arbitrary data/json. I searched around for things like "raspberry pi rc receiver" and "USB rc receiver" but apart from some tips on how to turn your raspi into a transmitter to an rc car (for which I don't know the range), I can't find anything about longer range receivers for the pi, or rc transmitters to attach to my laptop with which I can just send and receive arbitrary json.

Does anybody know whether there are any simple modules which I can attach to my raspi and laptop to send json with this rc technology to and from the pi over a range of at least 200 meters? All tips are welcome!

Comment: tiny antennas have tiny areas to gather in the EM energy. You need to use a much lower frequency than WiFi.

Comment: Most serious hobby RC gear uses the nRF24, its semi/compatibles, or incompatible competitors like the A7105 or (EOL) CYRF6936.  **But a pi is a grossly unsuitable choice for an autopilot**.  That is a job for an MCU with a *simple* software stack, not a desktop OS running off a flaky SD card.  You also don't want json for control, rather compact binary packets.

Comment: You will find the USB WiFi antenna's have much more range, but it will cost you a USB port on your Rpi, and a change in some files so eth0=wlan0, and shutdown the internal WiFi. The whip antenna may imbalance your rc plane. The above comments are important as well. Just creating a control panel (in Python 3) to flash some LED's in sequence used 10% of the CPU's resources. The Pi is a toy for children. It is not even a complete basic motherboard. It has no RTC. It has no shutdown sequencer unless you buy one as a pi-hat. It has no multi-task queue. Fast interrupts can damage the SD card.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf - but I see systems such as the Flysky fs-i6 with the FSiA6B receiver, which operate on 2.4GHz but according  to some reviews still manage to get a range of 400meter to 4km on a clear day. Wifi is also on 2.4GHz, so why shouldn't I be able to get such a range?

Comment: Look at LORA modules. (ICs available but modules better cost/benefit). 
[One example](https://www.google.co.nz/search?num=40&source=hp&ei=-wYiXLW2Js24rQG2tIrwBw&q=lora+rfm95+arduino&oq=lora+rf&gs_l=psy-ab.1.5.0l10.933.5655..9868...0.0..0.338.2155.2-7j1......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..35i39j0i131j0i10.wHEwATO0vGc).  and [**A zillion examples**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=lora+rfm95+raspberry+pi&num=40&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGteXx47rfAhXHHTQIHRnwBfgQ_AUIDigB&biw=1282&bih=719)

Comment: @ kramer65  Better receivers (such as super-heterodyne, instead of super-regenerative) will allow longer ranges. Lower data rates allow narrow bandwidths, which rejects more electron noise and rejects more trash from other WIFi users; thus narrow bandwidths should allow longer ranges. Non-directional WiFi antennas likely are "whips" or 1/4 wave, or 3cm. If you transmit at 50MHz (or other legal low frequencies), the non-directional antennas will be 50X longer and will intercept 50*50X (2,500X) the energy, which extends your range by sqrt(2,500).

Comment: @analogsystemsrf  Range extension by using larger aerials is included in the path loss budget calculations. Using eg LORA gives an impressive 168 dB link budget. The losses due to the smaller aerial at eg 900 Mhz are easily made up for by the gains from the spread-spectrum achieved gains. 10 km + ranges with 100 mW TX power at 900 Mhz is doable.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - So I've read a lot the past days about nRF24 and I think that could be an option. I've ordered some simple nRF24L01+PA+LNA and some CH340T Serial port to USB adapter so that I can send and receice the nRF24 signal over usb from my laptop and my pi. I'll be experimenting with that. Question: is bidirectional traffic (like wifi) possible over nRF24 or is that only one way? And also: what Bit rate can I expect from that? Could I reach about 20kbps both ways with that setup?

Comment: Even WiFi is not full duplex.  You would build a system that changes direction quickly.  CH340 is an odd choice and unlikely to work (IIRC it is only the CH341 that has synchronous modes and even that would be odd).  An Arduino would be a better way to glue an nRF24 to a PC, but again **neither a PC nor a pi belongs here!**  This is a job for MCUs running *simple* software.  You have a lot still to learn.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - There is always a lot to learn, and that is exactly what I'm after. I do want to build this system with something bigger than an MCU. The reasons are that I'm building a self-learning system for which I need a database, Linux is what I know and I want to learn Golang.
Also; a raspi still reacts a lot faster than I can as a human. And since I can fly the plane, why wouldn't a raspi be able to do it? 
Anyway, you taught and inspired me with many things and ideas! Thanks a million for that!

Answer (score 2):

WiFi should be able to work well for your application.
[ESP8266](https://wiki2.org/en/ESP8266), [ESP32](https://wiki2.org/en/ESP32)  and their kin should be suitable. Operation with external antennas at 2.4 GHz can achieve ranges of many km - especially in ground to aerial operation.

---

But, **look at LORA ("Long Range") modules which should easily meet your needs.**
[LORA - Wikipedia](https://wiki2.org/en/LoRa). Ranges of "over 10km in rural areas" are cited (antennae unspecified) but there is every reason to expect that this range can be exceeded in ground to air operation with 'sensible' antennae.

LORA utilises 'spread spectrum' techniques to achieve astounding-but-true real-world link budgets of typically 168 dB. eg -148 dBm RX levels at 100 mW tx power (!).

ICs are available but modules offer vastly better cost-benefit.
There are numerous on web Raspberry Pi + LORA related pages.

[One example](https://www.google.co.nz/search?num=40&source=hp&ei=-wYiXLW2Js24rQG2tIrwBw&q=lora+rfm95+arduino&oq=lora+rf&gs_l=psy-ab.1.5.0l10.933.5655..9868...0.0..0.338.2155.2-7j1......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..35i39j0i131j0i10.wHEwATO0vGc).

[**A zillion examples**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=lora+rfm95+raspberry+pi&num=40&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGteXx47rfAhXHHTQIHRnwBfgQ_AUIDigB&biw=1282&bih=719)

[Digikey - LORA modules](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/rf-if-and-rfid/rf-transceiver-modules/872?FV=ffe00368&quantity=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&k=lora&pageSize=25)  - wow!!!

[Seeed Studio module from Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/seeed-technology-co-ltd/109990166/1597-1488-ND/7033232) - $US7.91/1 in stock (!)

[Datasheet for above](https://github.com/SeeedDocument/RFM95-98_LoRa_Module/blob/master/RFM95_96_97_98_DataSheet.pdf) - github

[Raspberry Pi LORA-GPS module](http://wiki.dragino.com/index.php?title=Lora/GPS_HAT) - $35 Digikey. Adds LORA to RasPi and can add GPS functionality with GPS input to RasPi serial port. When are you buying one ? :-).

[Wiki for above](http://wiki.dragino.com/index.php?title=Lora/GPS_HAT)

[LORA alliance](https://lora-alliance.org/) home page - more for reference.

---

LORA SPECIFICATION

Lora Specification for above RasPi module:

168 dB maximum link budget. <- !!!  (!!!!!)
+20 dBm - 100 mW constant RF output
+14 dBm high efficiency PA.
Programmable bit rate up to 300 kbps.
High sensitivity: down to -148 dBm.  <- natural consequence of power and link budget
Bullet-proof front end: IIP3 = -12.5 dBm.
Excellent blocking immunity.
Low RX current of 10.3 mA, 200 nA register retention.
Fully integrated synthesizer with a resolution of 61 Hz.
FSK, GFSK, MSK, GMSK, LoRaTM and OOK modulation.
Built-in bit synchronizer for clock recovery.
Preamble detection.
127 dB Dynamic Range RSSI.
Automatic RF Sense and CAD with ultra-fast AFC.
Packet engine up to 256 bytes with CRC.
Built-in temperature sensor and low battery indicator.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I don't think Lora would meet my needs, because it's more designed for very low traffic sensors. I need to be able to constantly send and receive messages to and from the rc plane. I check out the wifi modules you suggest. I'm currently trying with a Ralink RT5370 ( https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/cmDKvGPex) but that only gives me a range of about 75meters. Do you think the ESP8266 or ESP32 will give a better result? I mean: isn't my router also a limiting factor here?

Comment: Not really, neither wifi nor LoRa is really suited for this.  Not wifi because it has too much overheard and drastically too much state, and is optimized for speed not range.  LoRa could be used in some edge cases, but in general is not on suitable frequencies for the data rates needed, and is really designed for range cases beyond what would be permitted here anyway.  **There are sound reasons pretty much all unlicensed-operator aircraft systems today use simple 2.4 GHz packet radios** - re-inventing things without considering the factors that lead to those decisions is unwise

Comment: @Kramer I'll beg to differ with SOME of your &  ChrisStratton's perspectives. LORA is NOT a super low data rate, low energy use system (such as BLE et al). You'd note in the outline spec that I included a bit rate of up to 300 kbps (although that's 'cheating' as it relates to a lower link budget mode). . The RaLINK system is much more like the systems that Chris is objecting to. LORA is far closer to "bare metal" from the users perspective - regardless of what happens inside. | What minimum mean continuous data rate do you consider essential?

Comment: I need a data rate of somewhere between 20kb and 80kb (I'm still building, so not exactly sure yet). I never seriously considered Lora because of its purpose of low traffic sensors I always read about. I actually have a Lora Pi hat laying around which I haven't used yet. But as far as I know Lora does not support simulataneous bidirectional messages right? I thought a Lora module either sends OR receives at any given time. Or am I not correct?

Comment: If you read an actual Semtech data sheet the high data rates modes of LoRa chips are legacy FSK, not LoRA.  There are differences between what you learn about a technology from a module's marketing blurb vs spending months and months working with it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I agree re legacy modes & speed - I noted this in a comment above (on Dec 26) but NOT in my answer -> " ...  You'd note in the outline spec that I included a bit rate of up to 300 kbps (although that's 'cheating' as it relates to a lower link budget mode). " | I am aware of what the data sheet means and agree that my answer could be/should be clearer. | re "There are ..." Homily noted :-) -> the same material is in the data sheet, but it will be inobvious to the uninitiated how the various aspects interrelate .